# How to execute .bat file on IIS 8 MVC .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-8

i have .bat file in the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.bat` i write code on MVC .net,

```
public static void run_cmd(string batchscript,string args,string userid)
    {
        try
        {
            Process proc = null;
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = batchscript;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args + " " + userid;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("run cmd", ex.ToString(), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

    }
```

my code work on local machine VS 2015 but when i publish code to IIS not work,

how to fix it on IIS 8?

Comment: Did you confirm if the IIS user has permission to execute the file? This is just my guess because you didn't provide any information on any error messages you received on the server.

Comment: Yes any errors and any information and also any response of execute bat file,